# Passing a bash script error to the console in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, shell

I have a shell script that runs some acceptance tests for an application I'm working on. The scripts runs the tests, checks if there were errors and then exits with either 0 (success) or 1 (failure).

I have a rake task that calls the shell script, and then gets the result. The problem I'm having is, how do I pass that result to the rails console so that when I `echo $?` it will be equal the value returned by the shell script?

My current code is as follows:

```
def acceptance_tests
    system("./run_tests.sh");
    error_code = $?.success? ? 0 : 1

    result = error_code == 0 ? 'passed' : 'failed'
    puts ("The acceptance tests have #{result}.")

    SystemExit.new(error_code)
end
```

The tests pass / fail as expected when I run them, but after they are complete, I run `echo $?` and it's always equal to `0`.

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you need you own custom test infrastructure when Ruby has many good libraries for the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, changing the `SystemExit.new()` to `exit()` worked for me.

```
def acceptance_tests
    system("./run_tests.sh");
    error_code = $?.success? ? 0 : 1

    result = error_code == 0 ? 'passed' : 'failed'
    puts ("The acceptance tests have #{result}.")

    exit(error_code)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

SystemExit is an Exception, so raise it:

```
$ echo "raise SystemExit.new(5)" | ruby; echo $?
5
```